# Adobe JavaScript - Summing two values with a comma

Tags: javascript, replace, adobe, parsefloat, tofixed

This is my code so far:

```
this.getField("price_config").setAction("onBlur", "calcSumElementprice()");
this.getField("amount").setAction("Keystroke", "calcSumElementprice()");

function calcSumElementprice(){

var priceConfig = this.getField("price_config").value;
app.alert("type priceConfig "  + typeof priceConfig + " Number " + priceConfig);

var amount = this.getField("amount").value;
app.alert("type amount "  + typeof amount + " Number " + amount);

var totalElementPrice = priceConfig * amount;    
var totalElementPriceValue = totalElementPrice ? parseFloat(totalElementPrice) : 0;
var totalPrice = totalElementPriceValue;

this.getField("Elementprice").value = totalPrice.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
```

Either I select amount or enter something in price_config, then the calcSumElementprice function is called.

For example, if I enter 200 for price_config, the calculation works perfectly. price_config and amount are then of type number. It also works with numbers that contain a point, e.g. 200.99 .

But if I enter 200.99, then priceConfig becomes a string. And the whole calculation no longer works, of course.

hat do I have to change so that both number variants (200 = whole numbers; 200,99 = numbers with commata) work?

Comment: Try something like `var priceConfig = parseFloat(this.getField("price_config").value);`

Comment: If I now enter 200,99, then priceConfig is of type number, but the number is 200.

Comment: You cannot use `,` as decimal separators in programming languages, input `200.99` instead of `200,99`. If you insist to use commas, try process it first and then convert it to a number (e.g. `var priceConfig = parseFloat(this.getField("price_config").value.replace(',', '.'));`)